# How to get multiple unique results from getElementById? JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a random character generator that can create several different characters at once, but I am having difficulty getting data to display on more than one id= tags. For example, data is generated for the first character's name but not the second one.

Is it possible to display unique results for both from the same array?

```
<span>Name:</span><span id="name"></span>

<span>Name:</span><span id="name"></span>
```

Html

```
var name = ["vin","hau","kin"]

    var randomName = name[Math.floor(Math.random() * name.length)]

    console.log(randomName);

document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = randomName
```

JavaScript

Comment: Element IDs must be unique. Perhaps you should use class instead of ID.

Answer (score 1):

You **don't**; having multiple IDs with the same value is **[invalid markup](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id)**.

Instead, you should have use of classes, and then use **[`.getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)**. This will return a **[NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList)** collection of elements, which you can loop over.

Also, your random name will only grab a random **letter** from your array. This is due to the fact that `name` changes the context in JavaScript, as **[`window.name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name)** has a special purpose, and should be a string. You'll want to change to something like `names`.

You'll also want to set this `randomName` **inside** of the new loop to ensure true 'randomness'.

All of this can be seen in the following:

```js
var names = ["vin", "hau", "kin"];
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("name");
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  var randomName = names[Math.floor(Math.random() * names.length)];
  elements[i].innerHTML = randomName;
}
```

```html
<span>Name:</span><span class="name"></span>
<span>Name:</span><span class="name"></span>
```

Comment: You could alternatively use that, yes. I prefer the original :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `document.querySelectorAll`. It takes CSS selectors. Never use the same id twice. That's just bad HTML.

Using [document.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) you can select all kinds of things.

select all elements with class="foo"

```
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.foo')
```

In other words it will select one and two but not three below

```
<div class="foo">one</div>
<h1 class="foo">two</h1>
<div>three</div>
```

select all divs that are direct children of element class="foo"

```
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.foo>div')
```

In other words selects one and two below

```
<div class="foo">
  <div>one</div>
  <div>two</div>
</div>
```

Select all divs that a class="foo"

```
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('div.foo')
```

In other words selects one and two below but not three

```
<div class="foo">one</div>
<div class="foo">two</div>
<hi class="foo">three</h1>
```

Select all pre elements

```
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('pre')
```

In other words selects two and three below

```
<div>one<div>
<pre>two</pre>
<pre>three</pre>
```

Select all element's who's id starts with "abc"

```
const elements = document.querySelectorAll("[id^=abc]");
```

In other words selects one and two below

```
<div id="abc1">one</div>
<div id="abc2">two</div>
<div id="def3">three</div>
```

It doesn't have to be `id`, it can be any attribute

```
const elements = document.querySelectorAll("a[href^=https://]");
```

Select all `<a>` elements who have an `href` attribute that starts with `https://` so would select one and two below

```
<a href="https://google.com">one</div>
<a href="https://duckduckgo.com">two</div>
<a href="http://bing.com">three</div>
```

One I've used recently

```
const elements = document.querySelectorAll("div[data-mystuff]");
```

select all elements that have a `data-mystuff` attribute so below would select one and two

```
<div data-mystuff="usa">one</div>
<div data-mystuff="canada">two</div>
<div>three</div>
```

Example

```
document.querySelectorAll('div[data-mystuff]').forEach((elem) => {
  console.log(elem.dataset.mystuff);
});
```

```js
document.querySelectorAll('div[data-mystuff]').forEach((elem) => {
  console.log(elem.dataset.mystuff);
});
```

```html
<div data-mystuff="usa">one</div>
<div data-mystuff="canada">two</div>
<div>three</div>
```

etc...

Also note that `querySelectorAll` is on all elements as well so you can use it to select things below a specific element. In other words

```
someElement.querySelectorAll('.foo')
```

selects all elements with `class="foo"` that are children of `someElement`